# I want to read an html tag which has formatted text. using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to read an html tag which has formatted text. For example

`<p id="strike" onMouseOver="getP()><b>Hello</b></p>` // paragraph Tag with formatted text

if i am calling a function,

```
 function getP()
 {  
       var val=document.getElementById('strike').value; 
    alert(val);
 }
```

am getting  undefined in alert, how to get the exact bold formatted text or bold tag with text....Please help me out in this

Comment: `.textContent` returns the plaintext, `.innerHTML` returns the HTML. There's no way to alert a boldfaced piece of text.

Comment: @Rob: I don't think he wants to alert it formatted, just to retrieve the text from the `b` element, and alert that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var val=document.getElementById('strike').innerHTML; 
    alert(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `alert(document.getElementById('strike').innerHTML);`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using:

```
function getP() {  
   var el = document.getElementById('strike').getElementsByTagName('b')[0],
       text = el.textContent ? el.textContent : el.innerText;
   alert(text);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8aqcR/1/).

Updated the above, and generalised some:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getP(el,tagtype) {
    if (!el || !tagtype) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var textFrom = el
    .getElementsByTagName(tagtype)[0],
            text = textFrom.textContent ? textFrom.textContent : textFrom.innerText;
   console.log(text);
    }
}
</script>

<p id="strike" onMouseOver="getP(this, 'b')"><b>Hello</b></p>​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8aqcR/2/).

Comment: Don't use `el.textContent` to check whether `'textContent'` is supported. When it's an empty string, It will be false when coerced to a boolean. The correct way to check whether it's supported is `document.textContent === null`. This follows from the fact that a node of type `DOCUMENT_NODE` has a `textContent` property which is equal to `null` (per [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent)). Example: `text = el[document.textContent === null ? 'textContent' : 'innerText'];`

Answer (score 0):

`p` does not have `value` property. You need to get the first childNode which is `b`, and access the `innerHTML` property.

```
   var val=document.getElementById('strike').childNodes[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var val=document.getElementById('strike').innerHTML;
```